# is exist a server-side constant-id generator lib or framework like android resource framework?

Tags: java, android, server-side

is exist a server-side constant-id generator lib or framework like android resource framework?

1. define constant variable by xml or properties.
2. auto generate java static constant.
3. intergate with ide or build tools,such as maven.

java server-side general use ResourceBundle to load string constant by property name.but it has tow disadvantage:

1. it hard to refer in java code.
2. it hard to check if miss pre define variable.